# check if list has already been created

Tags: list, powershell, client-object-model

I've written a bit of powershell for creating a list just wondering how add say an if statement to check if its already been created. In Client side not server side
here is my code :

```
   param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listName

)

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$context.Credentials = $credentials
$web = $context.Web 
$context.Load($web)    
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListInfo.Title = $ListTitle
$ListInfo.TemplateType = "100"
$myList = $web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
$myList.Description = $ListTitle
$myList.Update()
$Fields=$myList.Fields
$context.Load($Fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$list1 = $web.Lists | where{$_.Title -eq $listName1}if($list1){// Execute if list exists}
```